# I've been trying to get a redirect to work... using perl and a simple html page, redirect does not occur

Tags: html, perl, redirect

this is the html form... simple form with 1 field... I eventually will incorporate some logic to control when the redirect is done, but for now, all I want is to see it work... I have tried several methods, and nothing has worked... I have stripped down the code to the bare basics, but still no joy...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>query your team</title>      
</head>
<body>
    <h2>team query form</h2>
<form  method="post" id="newform" action="cgi-bin/team_disp.pl">

<div style="padding-left:30px; padding-top:50px;">
<div style="padding-top:75px;">
 <p>Enter Search Criteria </p>
</div> 
<div style="margin-top: -15px;">
<input type="text" name="srchtxt" maxlength="100" length="50">
<input type="submit" value="Search">

</div>
</div>
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

and here's my perl script... just trying to get redirect to re-paint the screen with the "referer"...  again, I tried multiple ways to get this, but it would never render... I am not sure if my site is disallowing redirects? I have had some near misses, but nothing redirects the actual page... I see the referer is set properly, but my attempts to manually set it, or refer to it have thus far failed...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
# use strict;
 use warnings;
 use DBI;
use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw(warningsToBrowser fatalsToBrowser); 
use CGI qw(redirect referer);
use CGI qw/:standard/;

print "Content-type: text/html \n\n";

$db_handle = DBI->connect("dbi:mysql:database=fauqu001_fqdb;host=fauqu001.mysql.guardedhost.com;;user=fauqu001_fqdb;password=t8rdG^h6sC2f")
    or die "Couldn't connect to database: $DBI::errstr\n"; 

read(STDIN, $buffer, $ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'});
@pairs = split(/&/, $buffer);
foreach $pair (@pairs) {
        ($name, $value) = split(/=/, $pair);
        $value =~ tr/+/ /;
        $value =~ s/%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])/pack("C", hex($1))/eg;
        $FORM{$name} = $value; 
        print '<br><h3>',$name,' = ',$value,'</br>';

        }
my $query = CGI->new();
my $referrer = $ENV{HTTP_REFERER};

    print $query->redirect($referrer);


my $xdate = `date`;

my $cgi = new CGI;
 print $cgi->header();
 print 'user_agent(): ' . $cgi->user_agent() . '<br>';
 print 'remote_host(): ' . $cgi->remote_host() . '<br>';
 print 'script_name(): ' . $cgi->script_name() . '<br>';
 print 'referer(): ' . $cgi->referer() . '<br>';
 print 'request_method(): ' . $cgi->request_method() . '<br>'; 

end;
```

Comment: There are so many modern and useful frameworks to work with nowadays. CGI is ancient and I would recommend using something else.
How about: Dancer2 ( https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer2 ), Mojolicious ( https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious ), or, my personal favorite Catalyst ( https://metacpan.org/pod/Catalyst ). There are excellent tutorials for all of those, and they also offer helper scripts to get you started quickly.

Comment: On another note, I do not like digging through a load of syntax errors that get spit out after uncommenting the `use strict` line. I recommend to always `use strict` and actually fixing errors that come up before posting.

Comment: Why don't you do a redirect via HTML ( https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H76.html ), using `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='http://redirectedsite.com/'" />`?

Comment: @bytepusher CGI still has its uses. However, the real problem with the code, despite the fact that there are **three** `use CGI` statements, the OP uses code from early 90s to parse a CGI request.

Comment: Update - I wasn't  reading enough... found out you can't have STDOUT and try to redirect...  Or at least you can't write    print "Content-type: text/html \n\n" and then try to redirect...

Comment: Of course you can't ... You can only provide a [single HTTP response](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html). You can't both provide content and redirect.

Comment: It is ridiculous to comment out `use strict`—the first line of defence—and then ask others for help. It is also rude to post such awkwardly-formatted code when you are hoping for free help from experts. Please address this in future.

Answer (score 1):

The redirect header needs to be part of the headers returned by your CGI program. The headers are the first data returned by your program. They are terminated by the first blank line in your program's output. More specifically, the headers are terminated when your program emits two consecutive line-end characters.

Early in your program you have:

```
print "Content-type: text/html \n\n";
```

That `print()` statements ends with two consecutive line-end characters. Therefore, your program can emit no more headers after this point. Any data returned by your program after this point will be treated as the body of the response, not the header.

So when, several lines later, you run this:

```
print $query->redirect($referrer);
```

That won't be interpreted as a redirection header. It's just data in the body of your response.

A useful tip in a CGI program: Work out exactly what you want to return before you return anything at all. You needed to print the redirection header instead of the content type header. But because you had already printed the content-type header (and, more importantly, the end of headers marker) it was too late to change your mind and print a different header.

Your program shows many signs of being cannibalised from several other programs without any real understanding of what you are doing.

You load the CGI library three times:

```
use CGI;
...
use CGI qw(redirect referer);
use CGI qw/:standard/;
```

You create two CGI objects:

```
my $query = CGI->new();
....
my $cgi = new CGI;
```

You ignore CGI's parameter parsing code and use a buggy hand-written version:

```
read(STDIN, $buffer, $ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'});
@pairs = split(/&/, $buffer);
foreach $pair (@pairs) {
        ($name, $value) = split(/=/, $pair);
        $value =~ tr/+/ /;
        $value =~ s/%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])/pack("C", hex($1))/eg;
        $FORM{$name} = $value; 
        print '<br><h3>',$name,' = ',$value,'</br>';

        }
```

You explicitly load the `referer()` function from CGI.pm, but then get the value using an environment variable:

```
use CGI qw(redirect referer);
...
my $referrer = $ENV{HTTP_REFERER};
```

You don't just print the two header sets that I've mentioned above. You find time to add a third later on.

```
print "Content-type: text/html \n\n";

print $query->redirect($referrer);

print $cgi->header();
```

I assume (I hope!) that you're just learning Perl and CGI. But this random poking at stuff until it works really isn't the best way to do it. Please find [a good tutorial](http://perl-tutorial.org/) and spend time understanding what is going on here.